# How to use two different aggregate functions within crosstab in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas, is it possible to compute a crosstab containing values from two different aggregate functions?

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b','b','a','a'], 'col2': ['g1', 'g1','g2','g2','g2'], 'col3': [3, 4,5,6,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
pd.crosstab(index=df['col1'], columns=[df['col2']],
                    values=df['col3'],
                    aggfunc=[sum,count])
```

I would like a table with count and sum values

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3',
               aggfunc=['sum','count'])
```

Output:

```
     sum     count   
col2  g1  g2    g1 g2
col1                 
a      3  12     1  2
b      4   5     1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be?

```
      g1                g2 
col2  sum  count    sum  count
col1                 
a      3  12          1  2
b      4   5          1  1
```